# How can I capture screenshot in react native not for the same app

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating an app (my-app) in react-native. I want to take screenshot of every screen of user's running app (like if xyz app is also open in background so can I take screenshots of it progmatically?).

I can also make a bridge from React-Native to Android if it is worthy.

Else suggest me something how can I achieve in Android (but I want in React-Native)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a screenshot of what the user is doing inside YOUR APP,
you can use [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot). But if you want to take a screenshot of the user's other apps, you can not do it on iOS as apps run in a sandbox on iOS. I do not know if it is doable on Android though.

Comment: Thanks Parsa, But I want to take screenshots for all background working app where user switch.
This module capture for only my-app.